# Как исправить ошибку в Microsoft Visual C++ 2010? (код ошибки C3265)

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Возникают ошибки:
"Нельзя объявлять управляемый descryp в неуправляемом state"
"Нельзя объявлять управляемый nam в неуправляемом state"

Код (язык C++):

```
class state
{
protected: 
    System::String^ descryp;
    System::String^ nam;
    //Продолжение описания...
};
```

Как исправить?
PS:Использовать символьные массивы в моем коде неудобно.

Comment: у Вас с++ или c++/cli?

Comment: У меня c++ (НЕ cli)

Comment: тогда Вы никак не можете использовать `System::String^`. скорее всего Вам нужен `std::string`

Comment: Значит, перепутал. На `std::string` он ругается (не существует)

Comment: `#include <string>` вверху добавили?

Comment: с `std::string` не работает. А с `System::String^` (похоже, у меня все-таки c++/cli) не пробовал.

Comment: С `System::String` тоже не работает.

Comment: Фраза "не работает" - ничего не объясняет. Нужно либо вывод компилятора, либо скриншот на худой конец.

Comment: у Вас c++/cli, тут я не помощник.

Comment: Управляемые члены можно объявить только в управляемых классах. Измените "class" на "ref class" и всё будет работать.